# Unifiyng lines with awk

Tags: awk, sed, command-line, cut, syntax

I have the file/text bellow:

```
apple 1
apple 2
apple 3
banana 22
banana 5
string 1
```

How can I run a command to return the following result?

```
apple numbers:1,2,3
banana numbers:22,5
string numbers:1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) show us what you have so far. What did you try? Did it work? How did it fail? We need to know so we don't give you the same solutions. ii) are there _always_ just two space separated values on each line? Or can you have things like `red orange 43`? iii) how important is the specific formatting you have? Does it need to be `numbers:` and then a comma separated list? Or would you also be OK with something like `apple 1 2 3`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{ n[$1] = (n[$1] == "" ? $2 : n[$1] "," $2) } END { for (f in n) printf "%s numbers:%s\n", f, n[f] }' file
apple numbers:1,2,3
banana numbers:22,5
string numbers:1
```

This uses `awk` to solve the task.

The `awk` program maintains an associative array `n` (for "numbers") into which the fruit name in the 1st column is used as a key.  The value of `n` for a particular fruit is a string of comma-delimited numbers, built up by the first block of code.

The funny looking code in that first block of code assigns the value from the second column to `n[$1]` if `n[$1]` is empty, otherwise it appends a comma and the value to the existing value.

The `END` block prints out the resulting data from `n` by iterating over all keys.